# Counting small subgraphs in an Erdős–Rényi graph with constant edge probability

Tags: probability-theory, random-graphs

Let $0<p<1$ and $n$ be and integer.
Let $\mathbf G(n, p)$ be the probability space whose underlying set is all graphs on the node set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, and the probability assigned to a graph $G$ having $m$ edges is $p^m(1-p)^{\binom{n}{2}-m}$. This is same as saying that an edge appears with probability $p$. In other words, this is the Erdos-Renyi model.

Let $k<n$ and let $\mathcal I_{k, n}$ denote the set of all injective maps from $\{1, \ldots, k\}$ to $\{1, \ldots, n\}$.
We denote the cardinality of $\mathcal I_{k, n}$ by $(n)_k$.
Note that $(n)_k= n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$.

Fix a graph $F$ on the node set $\{1, \ldots, k\}$.
We say that a map $\varphi\in \mathcal I_{k, n}$ is an **induced embedding** of $F$ in $G\in \mathbf G(n, p)$ if for all $1\leq i< j\leq k$, $\{\varphi(i), \varphi(j)\}$ is an edge in $G$ if and only if $\{i, j\}$ is an edge in $F$.
In other words, $\varphi\in \mathcal I_{k, n}$ is an induced embedding of $F$ in $G$ if the induced subgraph of $G$ by the image of $\varphi$ is $F$.

---

Define a random variable $X:\mathbf G(n, p)\to \mathbf R$ as 
$$X(G)= \frac{|\{\varphi\in \mathcal I_{k, n}:\ \varphi \text{ is an induced embedding of } F \text{ in } G\}|}{(n)_k}$$
Endowing $\mathcal I_{k, n}$ with the uniform probability measure, $X(G)$ is basically measuring the probability that an injection $\varphi\in I_{k, n}$ happens to be an induced embedding of $F$ in $G$.

If $F$ has $r$ edges, then it is easy to see that $E[X]=p^r(1-p)^{\binom{k}{2}-r}$.
**I want to show that $X$ is concentrated around it's expectation.**

---

I have tried the following (which you may ignore if you can see how to prove the concentration result):

I want to find the second moment of $X$, for which I need to find $E[X^2]$
For $\varphi\in \mathcal I_{k, n}$ and $G\in \mathbf G(n, p)$, let $\delta(\varphi, G)$ be $1$ if $\varphi$ is an induced embedding of $F$ in $G$ and $0$ otherwise.

Now
$$E[X^2]= \sum_{G\in \mathbf G(n, p)}P[G] \frac{|\{\varphi\in \mathcal I_{k, n}:\ \varphi \text{ is an induced embedding of } F \text{ in } G\}|^2}{(n)_k^2}$$
Thus
$$E[X^2] = \sum_{G\in \mathbf G(n, p)} P[G]\frac{\left(\sum_{\varphi\in \mathcal, I_{k, n}}\delta(\varphi, G)\right)^2}{(n)_k^2}$$
which gives 
$$
E[X^2] = \sum_{G\in \mathbf G(n, p)} P[G]\frac{\left(\sum_{\varphi\in \mathcal, I_{k, n}}\delta(\varphi, G)\right)}{(n)_k^2} + \sum_{G\in \mathbf G(n, p)} P[G]\frac{\sum_{\varphi, \psi\in \mathcal I_{k, n}:  \varphi\neq \psi}\delta(\varphi, G)\delta(\psi, G)}{(n)_k^2}
$$

which gives

$$
E[X^2] = \frac{E[X]}{(n)_k} + \sum_{G\in \mathbf G(n, p)} P[G]\frac{\sum_{\varphi, \psi\in \mathcal I_{k, n}:  \varphi\neq \psi}\delta(\varphi, G)\delta(\psi, G)}{(n)_k^2}
$$

I am unable to estimate the second term.
Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation you are using seems too cumbersome to work with. You basically never want to have an explicit sum over random graphs $G$ with $P(G)$ in it; such a sum is always an expectation of some random variable.

First of all, it will make our lives easier with we work with the random variable $Y = (n)_k X$. This is an integer random variable that counts the induced copies of $F$ in $G$. And if $Y \sim \mathbb E[Y]$, then $X \sim \mathbb E[X]$, because both sides are off by the same factor of $(n)_k$.

Second, for a fixed $\varphi \in \mathcal I_{n,k}$, let $Y_\varphi$ be the random variable that is $1$ if it's an induced embedding, and $0$ otherwise. (When we're not in a sum over $\varphi$, I will use $Y_\varphi$ to denote an arbitrary one of these, since they're identically distributed.) Then we have $$Y = \sum_{\varphi \in \mathcal I_{n,k}} Y_\varphi = (n)_k \mathbb E[Y_\varphi]$$ and your formula becomes
$$
   \mathbb E[Y^2] = \mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{\varphi \in \mathcal I_{n,k}} Y_\varphi\right)^2\right] = \sum_{\varphi} \mathbb E[Y_\varphi] + \sum_{\varphi \ne \psi} \mathbb E[Y_\varphi Y_\psi] = \mathbb E[Y] + \sum_{\varphi \ne \psi} \mathbb E[Y_\varphi Y_\psi].
$$
(We will not actually need to separate out the diagonal terms contributing to the $\mathbb E[Y]$, but it won't hurt anything either, and I wanted to match the expression in the question.)

Next, the key thing that often happens in use of the second moment is that the second sum here contains many pairs $(\varphi,\psi)$ whose images are disjoint; in that case, $Y_\varphi$ and $Y_\psi$ are independent, and so $\mathbb E[Y_\varphi Y_\psi] = \mathbb E[Y_\varphi] \mathbb E[Y_\psi] = \mathbb E[Y_\varphi]^2$. Moreover, the number of such pairs is at most $(n)_k^2$: the total number of pairs $(\varphi,\psi)$. So the contribution from independent pairs is at most $(n)_k^2 \mathbb E[Y_\varphi]^2 = \mathbb E[Y]^2$, and we get
$$
   \mathbb E[Y^2] \le \mathbb E[Y]  + \mathbb E[Y]^2 + \sum_{\varphi \sim \psi} \mathbb E[Y_\varphi Y_\psi]
$$
or
$$
   \operatorname{Var}[Y] = \mathbb E[Y^2]- \mathbb E[Y]^2 \le \mathbb E[Y] + \sum_{\varphi \sim \psi} \mathbb E[Y_\varphi Y_\psi].
$$
(where by $\varphi \sim \psi$ I denote the sum over correlated pairs $(\varphi, \psi)$: those whose images are not disjoint).

It is a fact that if $\mathbb E[Y] \to \infty$ and $\frac{\operatorname{Var}[Y]}{\mathbb E[Y]^2} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ (see, for example, Corollary 4.3.3 in Alon and Spencer's *Probabilistic Method*) then by Chebyshev's inequality $Y \sim \mathbb E[Y]$ almost always.

In our case, $\mathbb E[Y] = O(n^k)$ because $(n)_k = O(n^k)$ injections each have a constant chance of being realized, so the first term is definitely $o(\mathbb E[Y]^2)$. (This is why I wanted to work with $\mathbb E[Y]$ rather than $\mathbb E[X]$: so that we could distinguish $Y$ and $Y^2$ asymptotically.)

In the second term, each expectation $\mathbb E[Y_\varphi Y_\psi]$ is $O(1)$, and the key is that there are only $O(n^{2k-1})$ terms in the sum: for each of $O(n^k)$ injections $\varphi$, there are only $O(n^{k-1})$ injections $\psi$ such that $\varphi \sim \psi$. (The two images have to share at least one vertex, so there are only $O(n^{k-1})$ choices for the remaining vertices.) As a result, the second term is also $o(\mathbb E[Y]^2)$, and we obtain concentration.

(I am assuming here that you wanted concentration as $n \to \infty$ with $k$ fixed, which remains unstated in the question. This method can also give a concentration result for specific $n$ and $k$, but in that case you have to make the use of Chebyshev's inequality explicit to get a bound.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have just one question. In the second last paragraph of your answer, the first line reads "... each expectation $E[Y_{\varphi}Y_{\psi}]$ is constant ..." Do you mean that $E[Y_{\varphi}Y_{\psi}]$ is same for all $\varphi$ and $\psi$ with $\varphi\sim \psi$, or do you mean that $E[Y_{\varphi}Y_{\psi}] $ is bounded by a constant? I think $E[Y_{\varphi}Y_{\psi}]\leq E[Y_{\varphi}]$ because $Y_{\varphi}Y_{\psi}$ is a characteristic function with smaller support than $Y_{\varphi}$.

Comment: I mean that it is bounded by a constant: it is $O(1)$ in terms of $n$. What you've said is also true, of course.